# Encoding in saved data in R (windows-linux portability)

Tags: r, encoding

Is there a way to `save` R objects in a portable way, so that the encoding would be preserved when I move the file from windows to linux or back?

For example, suppose I have this simple data.frame (created in R 3.4.1 with Rstudio 1.0.153/ Windows 10)

```
# I did this part on a Windows machine
df <- data.frame(Õ = 1:5, Ä = c("õäöü", "baa", "mää", "muu", "näu"))
save(df, file="baa.rda")
```

Link to the file `save`'d on windows: [baa.rda](https://owncloud.ut.ee/owncloud/index.php/s/iUEVeL4lg2D46IT)

Reading it in on a Linux machine (R 3.2.5, RStudio 1.0.136, Linux Mint Debian Edition) will result in ...

```
# now on Linux ...
load("baa.rda")
df
#      \xd5             \xc4
# 1    1 \xf5\xe4\xf6\xfc
# 2    2              baa
# 3    3        m\xe4\xe4
# 4    4              muu
# 5    5           n\xe4u
```

So to convert it back to the original form, I can use something like...

```
names(df) <- iconv(names(df), from="WINDOWS-1252", to="UTF-8")
# [1] "Õ" "Ä"
df$Ä <- iconv(df$Ä, from="WINDOWS-1252", to="UTF-8")
# df$Ä
# [1] "õäöü" "baa"  "mää"  "muu"  "näu"
```

When going in the opposite direction (LMDE --> Windows), it is just the column names that are messed up, and again, this can be corrected with `iconv`:

```
> names(df2)
[1] "Ã•" "Ã„"
> iconv(names(df2), from="UTF-8", to="WINDOWS-1252")
[1] "Õ" "Ä"
```

The problem disappears if I read in the data from text files (e.g., csv) and specify the correct `fileEncoding` ... so that might be a solution. Or writing a function to `iconv` everything in one shot.

But is there a simpler way to do it? (That is, to save a data frame in one platform and read it in in another, without worrying about how the text was encoded.)

And a related question, is the information on (assumed) encoding somehow included when `save`'ing R objects?

Comment: What is your locale? Run `sessionInfo()$locale` to find out.

Comment: My locale is set to `"en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8"` and when I run the code you've provided, I don't have any issues. I should note that I'm on a Mac machine though, version 3.4.2.

Comment: My locale: `"LC_COLLATE=Estonian_Estonia.1257;LC_CTYPE=Estonian_Estonia.1257;LC_MONETARY=Estonian_Estonia.1257;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Estonian_Estonia.1257"` (this is on the Windows machine -- I suspect it will be something else on the Linux machine, probably UTF-8 instead of 1257 but I'll check tomorrow). The code (i.e. `save`'ing and `load`'ing) has no problems per se, the problem appears only when I save it on Windows and load the saved object on Linux.

Comment: @Oliver Frost, I added a link to the file saved on windows -- can you open it on Mac? (I suppose there would be the same problem, i.e. you would see something like `\xf5\xe4\xf6\xfc`instead of the accented characters)

Comment: Maybe the solution would be to encode everything as UTF-8 ... as some recommend:  http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Comment: Sure. The file you linked me to works fine on Mac OS with the locale set to what I mentioned above. Interestingly, it also works just fine on a Windows machine with my default English locale and with Estonian (`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Estonian")`.) I don't know if this was your intention, but I can't replicate the encoding errors with that file.

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation is not enough to comment on your question, I'm posting answer directly.

Although I'm not a Linux user, saving workspace in session would be helpful.
(click Session at the top - save workspace as...)

After you saved ***.RData file, you can load the file next time.

Data you used in the previous session will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem likely to help because the same mechanism is used in saving single objects and saving a workspace (choosing to save workspace from a menu is essentially equivalent to typing `save(list = names(.GlobalEnv))`)